# How can Flash control where he time travels?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash-2014, the-flash

Both in the various comic book series and the 2014 TV Show, we have seen The Flash running so fast that he travels through time. How can he control the exact date and time he wants to arrive, when he is voluntarily travelling through time?

I don't think any such explanation is given on the show, but is it ever mentioned in the comics?

Comment: On the show, the very first time Flash (intentionally) traveled in time he was told to picture the time he was aiming for clearly in his mind.  They make no mention of how he steers his dimensional travel, though.

Comment: He uses his speed to set time target..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comics, Barry generally performs his feats of dimensional and temporal travel with the help of his invention [The Cosmic Treadmill](https://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Treadmill). It is generally explained as an aid in tuning his vibrations to the needs of what he is attempting.

[image: Flash running on the cosmic Treadmill]

The presence of a treadmill in the show's S.T.A.R. Labs is likely a reference to/setup for this.

[image: Treadmill from the TV show]

Comment: The second link was broken so I fetched an image from the show's treadmill, since I assume it was what your originally included.

Comment: In the TV show, he runs in particle accelerator. The target time he wants to go is determined by his calculated speed.